# Match upcase characters in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Please im tying to write a regex  that would match String only in upper case starting with A and can contain either numbers or ALPHABETS

I've tried,

```
^A(? :. *)
```

But  my example matches lower cases also.

Comment: Then what is the purpose of using `.` that match any char but line break chars? Use `[A-Z0-9]`.

Comment: Take a look [regex101](https://regex101.com/) it is very useful. Explain every character you tipe

Comment: I don't see any reason to downvote this question, why peoples are downvoting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex

```
  /^A[A-Z0-9]*$/g
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/k7SUQa/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
/^A[A-Z0-9]+$/
```

Don't put the `i` modifier at the end! That will make your match **case-insensitive** : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Here's a working demo: https://regex101.com/r/paBN88/1/

Comment: Don't mention it. Use, `*` or `+` depending if you require or not more characters after the first one. `+` means at least another character, while `*` means other characters are allowed but optional, so you can also match only `A` if you want to.

Comment: Please assuming i want to match all occurrences of a particular string in a paragraph that follows a pattern. How would i go about that? Played around with regex101.com, but having little issues

Comment: All occurrences can be matched with the `/g` (global) modifier. Should you want to match words in random places, the regex becomes a little bit complicated, as you're not matching from start till end of a single line with `^` and `$`. Instead you have to check whether the beginning of your match is either a start of the string (or paragraph) OR not a alphanum character: `/(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9]+).....`. Likewise, for the end of the pattern not an afphanum OR the end of the string: `.....([^[a-zA-Z0-9]|$)/`. Anything in between those two (the `.....`) is your matching pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regexp:

`^[A-Z \d\W]+$`

Thanks

Comment: This matches much more than strings starting with `A`.

Comment: This is matching anything but lowercase.

Comment: Looks better. The original question said that numbers were allowed.  Also -
 it won't match a bare `A`, but it's ambiguous if the OP wants that or not.